# mysql add multiple column to large table in optimised way

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, innodb, in-place

I wanted to add 8 new columns to a large mysql(version 5.6) table with innodb having millions of record. I am trying to achieve this in most optimised way.

- Is there any advantage of using a single query to adding all columns over adding 8 columns in 8 different queries. If so would like to know why.
- On specifying **ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE**, What all things i need to take care so that it wont cause any data corruption or application failure!

I was testing out ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE with the query.

```
ALTER TABLE table_test ADD COLUMN test_column TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK = NONE;
```

But its taking same time as the query ran with ALGORITHM=DEFAULT. What can be the reason.

Table which im altering is having only primary key index and no other indexes. From application the queries coming to this table are:

```
insert into table;
select * from table where user_id=uid;
select sum(column) from table where user_id=id and date<NOW();
```

Answer (score 2):

By "optimized", do you mean "fastest"?  Or "least impact on other queries"?

In older versions, the optimal way (using no add-ons) was to put all the `ADD COLUMNs` in a single `ALTER TABLE`; then wait until it finishes.

In any version, `pt-online-schema-change` will add all the columns with only a brief downtime.

Since you mention `ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE`, I assume you are using a newer version?  So, it *may* be that 8 `ALTERs` is optimal.  There would be some interference, but perhaps not "too much".

`ALGORITHM=DEFAULT` lets the server pick the "best".  This is almost always really the "best".  That is, there is rarely a need to say anything other than `DEFAULT`.

You can never get data corruption.  At worst, a query may fail due to some kind of timeout due to the interference of the `ALTER(s)`.  You should always be checking for error (including timeouts), and take handle it in your app.

To discuss the queries...

```
insert into table;
```

One row at a time?  Or batched?  (Batched is more efficient -- perhaps 10x better.)

```
select * from table;
```

Surely not!  That would give you all the columns for millions of rows.  Why should you ever do that?

```
select count(column) from table where pk=id and date<NOW();
```

`COUNT(col)` checks `col` for being `NOT NULL` -- Do you need that?  If not, then simply do `COUNT(*)`.

`WHERE pk=id` gives you only one row; so why also qualify with `date<NOW()`?  The `PRIMARY KEY` makes the query as fast as possible.

The only index is `PRIMARY KEY`?  This seems unusual for a million-row table.  Is it a "Fact" table in a "Data Warehouse" app?

**Internals**

(Caveat:  Much of this discussion of Internals is derived indirectly, and could be incorrect.)

For some `ALTERs`, the work is essentially just in the schema.  Eg:  Adding options on the end of an `ENUM`; *increasing* the size of a `VARCHAR`.

For some `ALTERs` with `INPLACE`, the processing is essentially modifying the data in place -- without having to copy it.  Eg:  Adding a column at the end.

`PRIMARY KEY` changes (in InnoDB) necessarily involve rebuilding the BTree containing the data; they cannot be done `INPLACE`.

Many *secondary* `INDEX` operations can be done without touching (other than reading) the data.  `DROP INDEX` throws away a BTree and makes some meta changes.  `ADD INDEX` reads the entire table, building the index BTree on the side, then announcing its existence.  `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` changes require rebuilding an index.

If the table must be copied over, there is a significant lock on the table.  Any `ALTER` that needs to read all the data has an indirect impact because of the I/O and/or CPU and/or brief locks on blocks/rows/etc.

It is unclear whether the code is smart enough to handle a multi-task `ALTER` in the most efficient way.  Adding 8 columns in one `INPLACE` pass *should* be possible, but if it made the code too complex, that operation *may* be converted to *COPY*.

*Probably* a multi-task `ALTER` will do the 'worst' case.  For example, changing the `PRIMARY KEY` and augmenting an `ENUM` will simply do both in a single `COPY`.  Since `COPY` is the original way of doing all `ALTERs`, it is well debugged and optimized by now.  (But it is slow and invasive.)

`COPY` is really quite simple to implement, mostly involving existing primitives:

1. Lock `real` so no one is writing to it
2. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
3. `ALTER TABLE new ...`  -- whatever you asked for
4. copy all the rows from `real` to `new`  -- this is the slow part
5. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;` -- fast, atomic, etc.
6. Unlock
7. `DROP TABLE old;`

`INPLACE` is more complex because it must decide among many different algorithms and locking levels.  `DEFAULT` has to punt off to `COPY` if it cannot do `INPLACE`.

Comment: optimised, i mean both faster and its impact on live aplication. mysql version is 5.6, i tried with add multiple columns in single query which is more faster. Evenhough i add single column or 8 column in single query, time taken is same.

Comment: @bijoshtj - That's good to know.  Sounds like that is the answer you wanted?

Comment: on query impact, it was not affecting any of my query listed above. and i still dont know how. :) . this is the result of my test on test environment. I would like to know how it works internally. I couldnt find any proper documentation for that.

Comment: I added "Internals".